# How to embed Asymptote 3D objects in Latex code when using Overleaf?

Tags: 3d, asymptote, overleaf

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}

Test.

\begin{asydef}
  usepackage("bm");
  texpreamble("\def\V#1{\bm{#1}}");
\end{asydef}

2d figure:

\begin{asy}
  size(10cm);
  draw(circle((1,0), 1.5), blue);
  draw(ellipse((1,0), 1.5, 0.5));
\end{asy}

3D figure:

\begin{asy}
  settings.output = "pdf";
  settings.prc = false;
  size(5cm,0);
  draw(unitcircle);
  import three;
  draw(unitsphere);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

If I comment out the second `\begin{asy} ... \end{asy}` part, my code is successfully compiled.

If I uncomment it, I get

```
Package asymptote Warning: file `main-2.tex' not found on input line 31.
```

In my real document (not the MWE above), the error I get is

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/media9/media9.sty:75:
media9 error: "su pport outdated"
!
! Support package l3kernel too old.
!
! See the media9 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>
!...............................................
```

Here's a Read&Edit link to my MWE:

https://www.overleaf.com/4761541czcjsg

Comment: Overleaf's TeX Live 2015 (Ubuntu wily) doesn't have compatible versions of `media9` and `latex3`, unfortunately -- that means `media9` and `asymptote` 3D objects won't work.

Comment: Additional note: the effect of `settings.prc = false;` is precisely to disable the creation of 3d prc objects. Also, `settings.output` should be `settings.outformat`.

Comment: btw, Overleaf is planning to upgrade TL2015 in Ubuntu soon, so that should help with `media9` and `latex3` compatibility when it happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Sorry for the late update here + disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)

Asymptote 3D now works on Overleaf after the [upgrade](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/435-tex-live-upgrade-november-2016) to TeX Live 2016. An example has been posted at
 https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/asymptote-3d-graphics/dkkcmszqzvcy .

Comment: when I use `import gsl;` the asymptote on overleaf does not work. I guess some modules including `gsl` have not intergrated into Overleaf so far